# Can't show generated thumbnail with cordova video editor plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

I'm using the ionic plugin video editor to generate the thumbnail from a video, the thumbnail gets generated but it doesn't appear in an  tag with the path "file:///".. i tried everything nothing works

Code example :

```
this.videoEditor.createThumbnail({ fileUri: transcodedVideo, outputFileName: output + "-thumb"}).then((outputFileName: string) => {   
   video.thumbnail = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("file://"+outputFileName);
}
```

Html :

```
<img ion-img src = {{video.thumbnail}} >
```